# Disks Utility Drive Settings – how does it work? (no documentation available)

Tags: hard-drive, system-settings, gnome-disk-utility

The **Disks** Utility gnome-disk-utility 3.10.0 has a lot of neat functions, but I can not find a documentation, especially about the options at **Drive Settings**. There can be several like *Standby Time*, *Advanced Power Management*, *Automatic Acoustic Management* or *Write Cache*, depending of the options the drive supports.

[image: Drive Settings - APM]
[image: Drive Settings - Write Cache]

How to use the Drive Settings in general? By default the switches at all settings tabs are "off" – but if I'm not mistaken, this means that the settings shown in grey are the drive's active default and only if you want to change that, you have to switch the settings tab "on" and change the setting accordingly. Right?

So this is a quite easy way to disable the write cache for specific hard disk drives for more security (prevent data loss in extreme situations), if you want to! The "old" way was to use hdparm on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `gdisks` hasn't seen much development lately, so the "old" way is the "new" way again...  The disadvantage of FLOSS at work.  :-(

So as development is stalled, manuals are probably never going to happen. ;-(

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...*